# Load PHP page within HTML page with Javascript On Page Load

Tags: javascript, php, html, phonegap, html-framework-7

I am trying to figure out how to load a PHP page within an HTML page when the page loads with pure JavaScript. Nothing fancy. Just want to use the HTML page as a dummy.

**Update 1:**

After much confusion I wanted to update my issue.

I am trying to port my PHP website into a web app using Framework7. F7 is a an html and javascript only based system and doesn't play well with PHP. Not only that I am going to use phonegap to build the app, which also does not accept php.

Now I am trying to ask how I can use javascript/ajax to load a .php page within an .html page when the html page loads. Not when I button is clicked.

Basically I am using the .html files as dummy files just to load my php files within them.

If someone can suggest an easier way to approach this, I'm all ears.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are asking. Do you want the .php to be interpreted, or loaded as text? What is it that you are trying to achieve? Without further information this feels like [an XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: Thanks Jason. I updated my post a bit to clarify.

Comment: if you are using phonegap then you can load webview. this webview can be php with framework7.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do this with `<iframe src="yourfile.php" name="targetframe"  frameborder="0">
    </iframe>` and modify the css to display it however you want

Comment: I am using a javascript framework and want to load .php files within it. Iframes wont' help my issue, but I appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get content after loading the page. Than you should send an AJAX request. 
Like (pure JavaScript): https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

or with jQuery:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html"
}).done(function(e) {
  $( '.your-div').html(e);
});
```

Than you could load your HTML / PHP or else in to your page, after page loading.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to append an iframe:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = function() 
{
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = "none";
    iframe.src = 'the url goes here';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
};
</script>
```